# Can sizeof(size_t) be less than sizeof(int)?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, sizeof, size-t

Can `sizeof(size_t)` be less than `sizeof(int)`?

Do the C and/or C++ standards guarantee that using `unsigned int` for array indexing is always safe?

Comment: Why wouldn't using an `unsigned int` be safe? Array indexes can't be negative. Are you ever planning on having so many array elements as to overflow an `unsigned int`? It is technically possible for `sizeof(size_t)` to be more than `sizeof(int)` (ie, if `size_t` is `unsigned long long` on a 64bit system), but I doubt you will ever see it be less.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've seen some people from Java world thinking that array indices must be `int`. Maybe NoSkill is confused similarly?

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer that is because Java doesn't have unsigned types, like C and C++ do. Arrays in Java have lengths represented by `int`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question. He's wondering whether the range of `unsigned int` might be too large. e.g. `size_t == unsigned char`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Array indexes *can* be negative. For example: `int arr[10]; int *ptr = arr+5; ptr[-5] = 0;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: At least POSIX expects size_t to be `Unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator`.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer That is part of the C++ standard, that is not limited to POSIX

Comment: @KeithThompson That is not using a negative array index, though. That is accessing `arr[0]` using pointer arithmetic. `arr[-1]` is not valid, for instance. Neither would `ptr[-6]` in your example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The `[]` operator is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. The pointer is required to point to an element of an array object (including a non-array object that's treated as a 1-element array). If by "array index" you mean the index relative to the base of the array object into which the pointer points, then you're right, but the standard doesn't describe it in those terms.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The C standard does not use “array index” at all. The phrase is just plain words, which, on the face of them, describe an index into an array. By applying it to subscripts used with pointers, you are giving it a new and different meaning.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer In any *sanely* written class with array like behavior, array indices *are* signed integers: `array::operator[](int)` *not* `array::operator[](unsigned)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `sizeof(size_t)` can, in principle, be less than `sizeof(int)`. I don't know of any implementations where this is true, and it's likely that there are none. I can imagine an implementation with 64-bit `int` and 32-bit `size_t`.

But indexing an array with `unsigned int` is safe -- as long as the value of the index is within the bounds imposed by the length of the array. The argument to the `[]` operator is merely required to be an integer. It's not converted to `size_t`. It's defined in terms of pointer arithmetic, in which the `+` operator has one argument that's a pointer and another argument that is of any integer type.

If `unsigned int` is wider than `size_t`, then an `unsigned int` index value that exceeds `SIZE_MAX` will almost certainly cause problems because the array isn't that big. In C++14 and later, defining a type bigger than `SIZE_MAX` bytes is explicitly prohibited (3.9.2 [compound.types] paragraph 2; section 6.9.2 in C++17). In earlier versions of C++, and in all versions of C, it isn't explicitly prohibited, but it's unlikely that any sane implementation would allow it.

Comment: Moreover, if the sizes of objects are truly limited to values that can be represented by `size_t`, so that the original question is meaningful, an index of type `size_t` can express at least one value that is out of bounds for every array.  For substantially all arrays actually observed in real programs, a `size_t` can express *very many* out of bounds indexes.  Its association with the maximum possible size of objects, where that exists, does not make it safer for indexing.

Comment: "An implementation that supports arrays of more than SIZE_MAX elements will almost certainly make size_t bigger." is unclear.  Did you mean "An implementation that supports arrays of more than UINT_MAX elements ..." ?  An array, like any object, is size `SIZE_MAX` or less.  I suspect this in a C++ thing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No, I meant `SIZE_MAX`. C has no explicit requirement that objects can't be bigger than `SIZE_MAX` bytes. A C implementation could, for example, have 32-bit `size_t` but allow 2<sup>33</sup>-element arrays -- then `sizeof obj` could overflow.  The obvious solution would be for such an implementation to make its `size_t` big enough to hold the size of any object. Apparently this doesn't apply to C++14 and later.

Comment: Keith, Thanks.  "The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand" can also be read as  "C has no explicit requirement that objects _can_ be bigger than `SIZE_MAX`.  I'll grant that this is not explicit either way about can/can't be bigger... But the implication, IMO is _cannot_.  Looks like a good SO question unto itself.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It would be nice IMHO if that were stated explicitly. But I don't see how an implementation with 32-bit `size_t` that allows 2**33-element arrays would violate any requirement in the C (or C++ prior to 2014) standard. Possibly it's a case the authors didn't think of. IMHO `sizeof ...` can overflow just like any other arithmetic expression.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Which presumably is why C++14 added "Constructing a type such that the number of bytes in its object representation exceeds the maximum value representable in the type `std::size_t` is ill-formed." (3.9.2 [basic.compound] paragraph 3). This wording is not in C++11 (or in any edition of ISO C).

Answer (score 4):

[C answer]

> Can `sizeof(size_t)` be less than `sizeof(int)`?

Yes.  The size of `size_t` can be less, more or the same as `int`  as their relative sizes/ranges are not specified in C - only their *minimum* `_MAX` values: 65535, 32767.

IMO, `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(int)` is a [unicorn](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215113/detecting-unicorn-and-dinosaur-compilers).  Theoretical, but not seen.

Code could use the following to detect such beasties.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#if SIZE_MAX < UINT_MAX
  #error Unexpected small size_t
#endif
```

> Do the C and/or C++ standards guarantee that using `unsigned int` for array indexing is always safe?

In C, No.

Examples: A small array may only tolerate the indexes of [0 ... 2] - regardless of the type of the index - not the entire range of `unsigned`.  A huge array may be index-able [0 ... `UINT_MAX*42ull`]  and so an `unsigned` cannot represent all valid indexes.

A `size_t` is wide enough to index all arrays.